# Bootstrap 3: Push/pull columns only for smaller screen devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following layout on a page:

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">1</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">2</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">3</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">4</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">5</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">6</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">7</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">8</div>

 --------- ----- ----- ----- -
|    1    |  2  |  3  |  4   |
-------------------------------
|    5    |   6 |  7   |  8   |
```

But on smaller screen sizes I would like the following layout:

```
------- ----- ---
|    1    |  2  |
----------------
|    5    |   6 |
 ----------------
|    3    |   4 |
-----------------
|    7    |   8 |
```

What i am trying is:

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">1</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">2</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 col-xs-push-6">3</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 col-xs-push-6">4</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 col-xs-pull-6">5</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 col-xs-pull-6">6</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">7</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">8</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you use grid with 3 and 6 because you have other items that remain fixed. then try to create two columns and to place elements within columns

```
<div class ="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
   <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">1</div>
   <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">2</div>
   <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">5</div>
   <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">6</div>
</div>
<div class ="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">3</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">4</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">7</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">8</div>
</div>
```